# error: no matching function for call to 'TNode<Student>::TNode<const Student&)'

Tags: c++, linked-list, binary-tree, nodes

I am having this error whenever I want to add an element on a binary tree using templates on C++ and I'm having a difficulty on fixing it,

so here is my code is Tree.c file:

```
template <class Whatever>
ostream & operator << (ostream &, const TNode<Whatever> &);

template <class Whatever>
struct TNode {
    long balance;
    Whatever data;
    long height;
    TNode<Whatever>* left;
    long & occupancy;
    TNode<Whatever>* right;
    unsigned long & tree_count;

    TNode (const Whatever & element, Tree<Whatever> & theTree)
           :balance (0), data (element), height(0), left(0), 
           occupancy(theTree.occupancy), right(0),
           tree_count (theTree.tree_count) {
                occupancy++;
    }

    TNode (const Whatever & element, TNode<Whatever> & parentTNode)
     : balance(0), data (element), height (0), left (0),
            occupancy(parentTNode.occupancy), right (0),
            tree_count (parentTNode.tree_count) {
              occupancy++;
    }


template <class Whatever>
unsigned long Tree<Whatever> :: Insert (const Whatever & element) {
    //check to see if the tree is empty
    if(root == NULL)
    {  
         root = new TNode<Whatever>(element); //this is keep on giving me the no 
                                              //matching function error
         return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

and here is my Tree.h file:

```
template <class Whatever>
struct TNode;

template <class Whatever>
class Tree {
    friend struct TNode<Whatever>;
    long occupancy;
    TNode<Whatever> * root;
    unsigned long tree_count;
    static int debug;
public:
    //here are my constructor and destructor

    unsigned long Insert (const Whatever &);
```

and here is my Driver.h file:

```
class Student {
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, const Student &);
    char name[20];
    long studentnum;
public:
       //here are my constructor,copy constructor, and deconstructor
```

and i keep getting the error message whenever i try to compile saying,

Tree.c: In member function 'long unsigned int Tree::Insert(const Whatever&) [with Whatever = Student]:

Tree.c:140: error: no matching function for call to 'TNode::TNode(const Student&)'

Tree.c:48: note: candidates are: TNode::TNode(const Whatever&, TNode&) [with Whatever = Student]

Tree.c:40: note:           TNode::TNode(const Whatever&, Tree&) [with Whatever = Student]

Tree.c:31: note:           TNode::TNode(const TNode&)

anybody know how to fix this error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your `TNode` constructors take two arguments.  You are only passing one.

Comment: oh. Thank you, but now I'm having error: expected primary-expression before ')' token when i change it to root=new TNode<Whatever>(element, Tree<Whatever>);